# python elasticsearch DSL: Change aggregation size after initilization

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl-py

In part A of my application I build a bunch of aggregations for later possible use in a query like this:

```py
from elasticsearch_dsl import A

a = A("terms", field="some_field", size=10)
```

In part B of the application, I want to **change** the size of these aggregations and preferably *without accessing private member variables*. I know that this works:

```py
a._params["size"] = value_from_user_input
```

But it's not pretty and raises the linter. Is there another way?

I tried:

- looking at `elasticsearch_dsl.aggs` but got lost in the levels of abstraction and reflection
- saving only the params of the aggregation and instantiating them later. That is difficult however, since the aggregations are usually more complex than the example above and/or get nested inside other aggregations.